# Cauchy's Theorem and Cauchy's formula

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, complex-numbers, cauchy-sequences

I came across the following problem in our last midterm exam. I am completely stuck as to how to begin the solution:

If $|f(z)|\leq$ max $|f(z+re^{it})|$ ($0\leq t\leq 2\pi$), then $|f|$ has no strict local maximum within its domain of analyticity.

Currently I am familiar with Cauchy's Theorem and formula. I am not sure why even the first inequality is true? Can anyone lead to some hints/solutions?

Comment: Are you not familiar with the maximum modulus principle?

Comment: @EricTowers: No, I haven't learnt that yet. I have just begun Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: Well you can use cauchy's formula to prove the mean value property and with that you can prove the maximum modulus principle but that seems like a lot of work for just a single question.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the problem is suppose to be. Exactly what are the conditions on $f$? Are you assuming that $f$ is an analytic function, then trying to show the inequality, and then use the inequality to conclude that $|f|$ has no strict local maximum? Is the statement for all $z$? Also, are there conditions on $r$? (Is it for some particular $r$? For all $r$?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to give you a hint based on the assumption that you are trying to prove the following statement (without the use of the maximum modulus principle):

If $f$ is a (complex) analytic function on a domain $D$, then $|f|$ does not have a strict local maximum.

Pick any $z$ in the domain, and choose any $r$ so that the closure of the disk of radius $r$ centered at $z$ is still inside the domain $D$.

Then, the Cauchy integral formula tells you:

$$f(z) = \dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|w - z| = r} \dfrac{f(w)}{w-z} dw$$

Now, what happens to the integral when you substitute $w = z + r e^{it}$?  Can you obtain the inequality after making that transformation?

Assuming that you were able to complete the computation, what this shows is that the inequality

$$|f(z)| \le \max |f(z+r e^{it})|$$ for all , $t\in [0,2\pi]$ and $z$, $r$ that makes the expressions above defined.

Now, suppose that $|f|$ does have a strict local maximum at some point $c$. What happens if you apply the above inequality to $c$?

Comment: @Rameh I purposely left out some key details. Let me know if you want more details.

Comment: so what happened when you apply the that to $c$? Where would I put $c$ in in the inequality?

Comment: Replace $z$ with $c$.

Comment: so how does that contradict that c cannot be the peak of the graph?

Comment: Being a strict local maximum means that $|f(c)| > |f(z)|$ for all $z\ne c$ in some open set containing $c$. This open set containing $c$ will contain a disk centered at $c$ of some radius $r$. So in particular, $|f(c)| > |f(c+r e^{it})|$ for all $t \in [0,2\pi]$, which implies $|f(c)| > \max |f(c+re^{it})|$.

Comment: Thanks! would the same argument work for if one wants to justify that $f$ is analytic and never zero on domain $D$, then $f$ has no local minimum?

Comment: In essence, yes. But you'll need to make some changes.

Comment: I am aware of that, have been thinking about it since yesterday. Is it possible to show that by contradiction like above?

Comment: @Akaichan The key is the part $f$ is never zero. What can you do to a function that's never zero?